# Why does my setOnClickListener only apply to last element each loop pass?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, onclicklistener

Sorry if the code is a bit convoluted, I've been spamming things out trying to fix this for ages.

I create children within a layout and track the number in which they were added, then compare them so we know which sets belong to which exercises. On click of the arrow, the set information should collapse but only the last view of each exercise does.

[fully loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atk6D.png)

[clicking to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Volke.png)

[all buttons clicked to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnL8j.png)

```
    fun listeners() {
for (i in childCount3) {
    val imageButton: TextView = binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i).weightTxt
    val fragment = EditSetFragment()
    imageButton.setOnClickListener {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.parent_linear_layout, fragment).commit()
    }
}
// childList = 10 | childList2 = [0,3,6,8] | childList3 = [1,2,4,5,7,9]
var testCount = 0
var testCount2 = 0
for (i in 0 until childCount2.size) {
    var matches = ArrayList<Int>()
    val imageButton: ImageButton = binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(childCount2[i]).expandCard
    Log.d("I  ", i.toString())
    for (k in 0 until childCount3.size) {
        Log.d("k  ", k.toString())
        Log.d("CHECKER  ", binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(childCount2[i]).instanceTxtEx.text.toString() + binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(childCount3[k]).instanceTxt.text).toString()
        if(binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(childCount2[i]).instanceTxtEx.text == binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(childCount3[k]).instanceTxt.text) {
            matches.add(childCount3[k])
            Log.d("MATCH  ", i.toString())
            imageButton.setOnClickListener{
                binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(childCount3[k]).visibility = GONE
            }

        }   
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow what you're doing, but I think you're going over each item in `childCount2`, grabbing its expand button, then trying to add a click listener for each child that item has in `childCount3`?

The problem is you can only set one click listener on a `View`, so in your loop you're not adding multiple listeners which each hide a button, you're replacing the current listener each time. So it ends up only hiding the last item you set a listener for.

If you're adding these items to the layout programmatically, can't you just store a list of the children of each top-level item? That way you can just set the listener once for each button, and in it just reference your list of its children. Something like this:

```
val parentsAndChildren = mutableMapOf<View, MutableList<View>>()

// Add your top-level (childCount2) views here, mapped to an empty list
// As you add children (childCount3), grab their parent's list and add the child to it

fun setUpCollapseButtons() {
    // iterate over all the parents and set a click listener on their buttons
    parentsAndChildren.keys.forEach { parent ->
        parent.expandCard.setOnClickListener {
            // grab the current list of children for this parent, and do the thing
            parentsAndChildren[parent].forEach { it.visibility = GONE }
            // could also do { it.visibility = if (it.visibility == VISIBLE) GONE else VISIBLE } for a toggle
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure how you're referencing things like `expandCard` when `getChildAt` just returns a `View`, but you can use `findViewById` on each `parent` when you're setting up the click listeners. Hopefully that gives you the idea - it's much easier to just keep track of the views themselves, instead of having to go digging for them (and doing text comparisons to match them)

---

If you still want to do it this way, here's how you can set one click listener on each:

```
// collect all the parent Views
val parents = childCount2.map { i -> binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i) }
parents.forEach { parent ->
    // collect all its children
    val children = childCount3.map { j -> binding.parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(j) }
        .filter { child -> parent.instanceTxtEx.text == child.instanceTxtEx.text  }

    // add a single click listener to the parent, make it affect all the children
    parent.expandCard.setOnClickListener {
        children.forEach { it.visibility = GONE }
    }
}
```

There are fancier ways to collect the parents and children, but hopefully that makes sense - you need to collect them all before you can set the click listener that affects them all

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, sorry for my bad explanation. It might be easier if I just describe what I'm trying to do instead. I have a server that sends JSON packages on request to the app. It pulls exercises and their related sets, so if the user has done bench press 3 times on a certain date it will pull the data for those sets. I'm attempting to create a box with a dropdown and the exercise information for each exercise, and then within each of those boxes when you click the dropdown, a separate box should appear with the information for the individual set.

Comment: Noting also that I realize that my method (there is a lot more code above this, almost 200 lines) is absolutely not the correct way of going about this - in short, all of these boxes, both exercise, and set are all under one parent [parentLinearLayout] holds both exercise and set. It should be parent [parentLinearLayout] contains [exercises] and each exercise contains [sets]. For the life of me cannot figure out how to do this correctly.

Comment: Updating: I implemented your second suggestion and it now works as I wanted. Still, if you have any easy-to-understand methods of doing what I said in the above comment it'd be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JosephHancock I feel like what you want to do is create an item layout for each exercise, which has all the exercise data and whatever, an open/close button, and a container (like a ``LinearLayout``) that you can add all the sets to. So you're actually creating a view hierarchy where the sets are children of a parent view representing the exercise - right now your hierarchy is completely flat (everything's a child of ``parentLinearLayout``). And then all you need to do is make that container layout visible/gone, and it'll show/hide everything in it

Comment: Can't really help with the JSON, but you should get it working with some test data first - set things up so you can find the appropriate parent layout, and add the set data to it (without duplicating an existing entry - I assume they have unique IDs). Once that's working, you can work on translating your JSON to the same structure your working test data uses. I still recommend keeping a map of your views (e.g. exercise ID -> exercise View) so you don't have to search the layout for them, but if you do still want to do that, the `setTag`/`getTag`/`findViewWithTag` `View` methods might be useful